# sqlite query android exception

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

please tell me what is wrong in this query:

getting following exception:

`android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "%": syntax error (code 1):` ,
 while compiling: `SELECT _data, _size, media_type FROM files WHERE ( _size > 1048576 AND media_type = 0 AND _data LIKE %apk)`

Comment: will be easy if some code is provided to crawl

Comment: he can not resolve the "%". What you want with this?

Comment: Post your sql building statement.

Comment: do like this `'%apk'`

Comment: try this : select _data, _size, media_type from files where ( _size > '1048576' and media_type = '0' and _data like '%apk')

Comment: i want the result that contains "apk" at the end. i.e. example.apk will be selected but example.ap will not be selected

Comment: @Rustam thanks to you also

Comment: shall i put as ans ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT _data, _size, media_type FROM files WHERE ( _size > 1048576 AND media_type = 0 AND _data LIKE '%apk')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed the quote after like operator 
[see this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you ti solve your problem.**

```
select _data, _size, media_type from files where ( _size > '1048576' and media_type = '0' and _data like '%apk')
```